# Copied Windows Phone 8.1 Project in new Windows 8.1 Universal Project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1-universal, shared-project

I am making a Windows 8.1 Universal app from an existing Windows Phone 8.1 App and an existing Windows 8.1 App. By copying the files and putting all the common files in the Shared folder correctly, the Universal.Windows app worked correctly. But the Universal.WindowsPhone app had errors in displaying the MainPage. Some scrollviewers (with the same heights and widths of the working old app) are getting displayed like if they have shorter heights.

Has anyone got a problem like this one before?